# Word problem I can't solve

Tags: word-problem

Hello I have been trying to solve this math word problem, I tried drawing a diagram and I came to the answer 2 but I am not sure about my answer and would appreciate some help Thanks!

Here is the question:

The interiors of all the unit squares of a 10 by 10  board are to be painted. Any two squares that have a side in common will be painted with a different colour of paint. What is the least number of colours that will be needed?

Comment: Where is the confusion?  $1$ is clearly not possible.  Can you see a configuration using $2$?  If so, that must be minimal.

Comment: How did you come to the answer of 2?

Comment: Like a chess board?

Comment: The simplest way to answer is with a diagram.  If you draw a small piece of the board it is easy to say it can be continued as far as you want.

Comment: Surely you have seen checkerboard patterns in your life?  Even if you hadn't and tried to guess and wanted as few as possible you say "well, the first square  is color 1.  I'll try to do all adjacent squares in color two to see if I can do that and... waadya know.  I *can* do that.'

Comment: Forget as "far as you want" 10 by 10 can be done very quickly.  And as lulu says.  The number immediately less than 2 is 1.  And that's impossible.  So the answer is 2.